# Retrieving variable length text from data files

Tags: antlr3

We have a requirement to extract variable length text blocks from our data files and have been trying to write a grammar file. There are two main challenges. First, text is of variable length. Second, there are no anchors which can help us locate the text blocks as such. Basically, we are trying to parse a mainframe generated text-based letter to extract the information from specific sections for file and then using the key-value pairs from ANTLR to populate a Adobe forms. In ANTLR 4.0 we identified a way to merge all the words for a token and merged them, space separated, to form a string. Since parsers and lexers were rewritten in 4.0, we don't have the same capability in 3.5. Seeking your inputs to crack the issues. Following are few things we have been trying.

We tried this approach of writing semantic predicate. We are able to get the words but we are unable to insert a whitespace between the words.

```
@init{ int N = 0; }
  :  ( { N <= 3 }? ) =>( WORD { N++; }  )+
```

This is the third approach of including white space. Instead of skipping the `WS` we can handle it in each rule but it may occupy a lot of memory which may cause the memory out of space issue.

```
name: WORD WS WORD WS WORD;
WS    : ( ' '|'\t'|'\r'|'\n' )+
```

Comment: Can you give an example input and desired output? I can't tell what you're trying to accomplish. Also, it appears you have access to ANTLR 4, but now you are trying to go backwards and use version 3... why?

Comment: Prime reason to go backwards was a conflict of ANTLR versions. Our project was using Drools which internally uses ANTLR 3.5. Maven was not allowing two version of ANTLR (3.5 & 4.0) to be present in same EAR. Hence we had to downgrade as drools component took higher rank.

Comment: I couldn't attach files here so sending you an email with required info.

Comment: ANTLR 4 uses different artifact names and package names from ANTLR 3. In fact, the ANTLR 4 tool itself is built using Maven and references both the 3.5 runtime and 4.0 runtime. The artifact name for the 3.5 runtime is `antlr-runtime`, and the artifact name for 4.0 is `antlr4-runtime`. You should not have any conflicts referencing both of them in the same project.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think I can help with a grammar for the input described in your email. Hopefully the tip about ANTLR 4 allows you to work with it alongside ANTLR 3. :)

Comment: Thanks Sam for your time. We are continuing our research. Just wanted to ask if you will not be able to help since you have time crunch or thing we are trying to achieve is impossible or difficult with ANTLR 3.5? We just wanted to makre sure that we are spending our energey at right place.